# How to obtain the electric potential in the limit a>>L , where 2L is the charged bar's length and a is the x-coordinate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential

The problem I'm having trouble with is this.
$$$$The insulating bar of negligible thickness has a length of 2L and the middle of the bar is located at (0,0). The point P where I have to locate the electric potential is at (a,0) (a>L). Assuming the bar has the charge density $\lambda(x)=\lambda_0x$, calculate the electric potential at P, and find the electric potential at the limit a>>L. $$$$
**Solution :**
I finished calculating the electric potential at P using integral, and obtained $V=k\lambda_0(a\ln(a+L)-a\ln(a-L)-2L)$. But the problem is the potential at the limit a>>L. My professor said it's definitely not 0, but if I keep using approximation it keeps on becoming 0. Any help to avoid 0 would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I assume $l=L$?

Comment: oops that's right sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

assuming your formula is right, try rewriting it likes this:
$$V = k\lambda_0a\left(\ln(a+l)-\ln(a-l)\right)-2Lk\lambda_0$$
Now try writing the two ln's as one using:
$$\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$
What's the limit of this logarithm now?